# Sqlalchemy dynamically create joins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a number of tables in `t`, and I want to join them all in the following way:

```
sa.select(['*'])
.select_from(
t[0]
.join(t[1], (t[1].c.id == t[0].c.id), full=True)
.join(t[2], (t[2].c.id == t[0].c.id), full=True)
...
.join(t[n], (t[n].c.id == t[0].c.id), full=True)
)
```

But the n varies at runtime. Is it possible to generate this query dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a loop to compute the result of the `n` joins:

```
t_joined = t[0]
for i in range(1, n+1):
    t_joined = t_joined.join(t[i], t[i].c.id == t[0].c.id, full=True)
result = sa.select(['*']).select_from(t_joined)
```

Or, if the intent is to simply iterate through all the tables in `t`, then the loop could be simplified to

```
t_joined = t[0]
for ti in t[1:]:
    t_joined = t_joined.join(ti, ti.c.id == t[0].c.id, full=True)
result = sa.select(['*']).select_from(t_joined)
```