# Programmatically rename multiple columns in query using SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a query where I am joining multiple tables and selecting all the columns. 
I would like to suffix each column in the result with the name of the table it came from. Is there a way to programmatically do this in SqlAlchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your question is related to the other one ([Sqlalchemy dynamically create joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639522/sqlalchemy-dynamically-create-joins)), here you go (I am extending accepted answer):

```
s_stmt = [
    col.label(col.name + '_' + ti.name)
    for ti in t for col in ti.columns
]

t_joined = t[0]
for ti in t[1:]:
    t_joined = t_joined.join(ti, ti.c.id == t[0].c.id, full=False)


result = select(s_stmt).select_from(t_joined)
```